# Replacing DOM text with jQuery

Tags: jquery, replace

I have a basic DOM "outline" that contains a table with dummy data like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>name</td>
    <td>phone</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

My script uses this as a dummy row to clone and replace the text between the TD tags with text from a database. Without copying the whole script here, here are two different things I've tried:

```
newRow.find("td.name").text(participant.name);

newRow.find("contains("phone")").text(participant.homePhone);
```

Neither one works. The script clones and displays the rows just fine, but I have 30 rows of "name" and "phone".

I used Firebug's console.log to debug and I am sure that it's got the data correctly from JSON, loaded into the "participant" parameter. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: really need to see the rest of the script / markup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second version is almost right if I understand what you are tring to do.  Note the colon preceding the selector and the use of inner single quotes.

```
newRow.find(":contains('name')").text(participant.name);
newRow.find(":contains('phone')").text(participant.homePhone);
```

Better yet would be to give the templates classes and use those or simply rely on the positioning.

Positioning:

```
newRow.find('td:first-child')
      .text(participant.name)
      .next()
      .text(participant.homePhone);
```

Classes:

```
newRow.find( 'td.name' ).text( participant.name );
newRow.find( 'td.phone' ).text( participant.homePhone );
```

Necessitating this change:

```
<table> 
  <tr> 
    <td class="name">name</td> 
    <td class="phone">phone</td> 
  </tr> 
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks.  I picked this one as the answer, although almost everybody told me to use classes.  Of course! It's working now.

Comment: @Carrie - Note that classes are a good way to do it.  I wouldn't use the `contains` method as you might have issues if someone's name includes the string `phone`, for instance.  The DOM-relative mechanism works well but is sensitive to changes in the table structure.

Answer (score 6):

you're using `td.name` which doesn't exist in your markup.  the `.name` denotes a class so you'd need markup like: `<td class="name"></td>` in order for that to work.

If you're using this as a dummy row and replacing those two td's, I'd supply a class to each like `<td class="name"></td><td class="phone"></td>` to use `newRow.find("td.name")` or use something like: `newRow.find("td:first")` and `newRow.find("td:last")`

Answer (score 2):

```
newRow.find("td:contains(name)").text(participant.name);

newRow.find("td:contains(phone)").text(participant.homePhone);
```

Comment: Now, what would happen if the participants name is Stephone Andrews?

Comment: hehe . i agree using classnames makes more sense, but i was attempting to correct his supplied logic & not redirect him to a better solution...

Answer (score 0):

`find('td.name')` looks for a `td` with a `class="name"`, which you don't have. I would recommend adding this to your HTML to create a hook for jQuery to update the text. Especially if you have several on the page.

Also, how are you setting `newRow`?